# When ever record owner changes branch and country field need to update automatically in Plugin Ms CRM

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

Retrieve the  Branch and Country of the Portfolio Owner of the record owner and whenever the user updates the record owner its corresponding branch has update automatically in the branch field(on custom entity). How should I proceed with this using the plugin in MS CRM?

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to use a plugin to do this? You could achieve this via Flow or even workflow.

Comment: need to trigger this on multiple entities at a time,hence i will register the steps on many entities